# Whats changes are needed when change the run enviroment of SWF game?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I want to change the runing enviroment of a Flash game from Web to Desktop(Windows).
The game sends and receives to a backend server.
As it is now it calls like :
var varURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../../index.php");

Running from a Windows App, it should be changed to the complete URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be changed to the fully-qualified URL where your script resides on your server; e.g.

```
var varURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://example.com/game-directory/index.php");
```

Note that you may well need to check the [cross-domain policy](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html) on the website where your scripts are hosted, and consider the [transport protocols](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) used, as some OSs may not allow it.

Comment: Note that it also comes down to how your app is being built & signed (as well as the end-user's own security) as to whether this will work as expected.

Comment: Changing the swf is getting complex.
Is there a tool or a way, that with a given server response look for the swf locally?

Comment: @CoderInside I'm not really sure what you mean, but feel free to post a separate question with details of what you're trying to do and what's happening.